# Intervalometer for Nikon D40?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, timelapse, nikon-d40, firmware

We have a seldom-used D40 that I'd like to use for some timelapse projects so as no to burn out my new D7000.

The D40 doesn't have a built-in intervalometer, and tethering to a laptop, while possible, isn't terribly practical for the type of shots I'm planning.

I'm seeking either a wired, wireless or exotic firmware solution to adapt the D40 for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same problem here. Have done some research, google these intervalometers, they should be compatible with D40: bigmike, Pclix, gentLED.

There are also some battery grips with built in timers. You should be aware that the D40 IR sensor's maximum is 15 minutes (goes to sleep after that), so that limits your intervals. The grips are limited to 99 shots/sequence.

Hope it helps, please reply if you succeed!
Mat

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're willing to consider an exotic solution, I did some Googling and it seems there aren't any ready-made and readily-findable intervalometer options for the D40.  But there seem to be a lot of build-it-yourself folks who offer solutions [such as this one](http://www.freekonline.net/2009/07/04/nikon-d40-intervalometer-project/).

Comment: Wow, I guess that fits the bill as exotic. I guess I should have clarified that I was thinking more along the lines of firmware hack, but this looks interesting.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: no longer dead! works as of June/2012

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is going to work for you:

http://www.diyphotobits.com/download-diyphotobitscom-camera-control/